# Error al importar un modelo Unhandled exception - cannot import name

Tags: python, django, django-models

Tengo la siguiente estructura de mi aplicación en relacion a las siguientes apps

```
project
    userprofile
        models.py
    rbsessions
        models.py
```

En userprofile/models.py tengo lo siguiente

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from rbsessions.models import Session

class User(AbstractUser):

    GENDER_MALE = 'M'
    GENDER_FEMALE = 'F'
    GENDER_OTHER = 'O'
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        (GENDER_MALE, u'Male'),
        (GENDER_FEMALE, u'Female'),
        (GENDER_OTHER, u'Other'),
    )

    AMERICAN_GROUP = 'AM'
    ASIATIC_GROUP = 'AS'
    AFROAMERICAN_GROUP = 'AFA'
    EUROPEAN_GROUP = 'EU'
    INDIGENOUS = 'IND'
    OTHER_GROUP = 'O'
    ETHNIC_CHOICES = (
        (AMERICAN_GROUP, u'American'),
        (ASIATIC_GROUP, u'Asiatic'),
        (AFROAMERICAN_GROUP, u'Afroamerican'),
        (EUROPEAN_GROUP, u'European'),
        (INDIGENOUS, u'Indigenous'),
        (OTHER_GROUP, u'Other'),
    )

    gender = models.CharField(
            max_length=1,
            choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
            default=GENDER_OTHER,)

    ethnic_group = models.CharField(
            max_length=3,
            choices=ETHNIC_CHOICES,
            default=OTHER_GROUP)

    birth_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())

    address = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)

    phone = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'phone', max_length=25, blank=True)

    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)

    country_of_birth = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)

    communication_language = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)

    is_medical = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    is_therapist = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', blank = False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super(User, self).save( *args, **kwargs)

        # Creating and user with medical, patient and therapist profiles
        if self.is_medical and not MedicalProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists()\
                and self.is_patient and not PatientProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists()\
                and self.is_therapist and not TherapistProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():

            medical_profile=MedicalProfile(user=self).save()
            patient_profile=PatientProfile(user=self).save()
            therapist_profile=TherapistProfile(user=self).save()
            #profile.save()

        # Creating and user with medical and patient profiles
        elif self.is_medical and not MedicalProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists()\
            and self.is_patient and not PatientProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():

            medical_profile=MedicalProfile(user=self).save()
            patient_profile=PatientProfile(user=self).save()

        # Creating and user with medical and therapist profiles
        elif self.is_medical and not MedicalProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists()\
            and self.is_therapist and not TherapistProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():

            medical_profile=MedicalProfile(user=self).save()
            therapist_profile=TherapistProfile(user=self).save()

        # Creating and user with physiotherapist and patient profiles
        elif self.is_therapist and not TherapistProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists()\
            and self.is_patient and not PatientProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():

            therapist_profile = TherapistProfile(user=self).save()
            patient_profile = PatientProfile(user=self).save()

        # Creating and user with medical profile
        elif self.is_medical and not MedicalProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():
            profile = MedicalProfile(user=self)
            profile.save()

        # Creating and user with patient profile -- Here --
        elif self.is_patient and not PatientProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():
            profile = PatientProfile(user=self)
            profile.save()
            encounter = Session(user=self).save()


        # Creating and user with therapist profiles
        elif self.is_therapist and not TherapistProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():
            profile = TherapistProfile(user=self)
            profile.save()



    # We get the profiles user according with their type
    def get_medical_profile(self):
        medical_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'medicalprofile'):
            medical_profile=self.medicalprofile
        return medical_profile

    def get_patient_profile(self):
        patient_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'patientprofile'):
            patient_profile = self.patientprofile
        return patient_profile

    def get_therapist_profile(self):
        therapist_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'therapistprofile'):
            therapist_profile = self.therapistprofile
        return therapist_profile

    class Meta:

        db_table = 'auth_user'

class MedicalProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    specialty = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)

class PatientProfile(models.Model):

    STATUS_SINGLE = 'S'
    STATUS_MARRIED = 'M'
    STATUS_WIDOW = 'W'
    STATUS_OTHER = 'O'
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_SINGLE, u'Single'),
        (STATUS_MARRIED, u'Married'),
        (STATUS_WIDOW, u'Widow'),
        (STATUS_OTHER, u'Other'),
    )

    PRIMARY_LEVEL = 'PRI'
    SECONDARY_LEVEL = 'SEC'
    UNIVERSITARY_LEVEL = 'UNI'
    MASTER_LEVEL = 'MAS'
    PHD_LEVEL = 'PHD'
    LEVEL_CHOICES = (
        (PRIMARY_LEVEL, u'Primary'),
        (SECONDARY_LEVEL, u'Secondary'),
        (UNIVERSITARY_LEVEL, u'University'),
        (MASTER_LEVEL, u'Master'),
        (PHD_LEVEL, u'PhD'),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    blood_type = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=False)
    marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, blank=False)
    educational_level = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=LEVEL_CHOICES, blank=False)
    care_provider = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)
    time_of_evolution = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)
    affected_limb = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)
    diagnostic = models.TextField(blank=True)
    managing_organization = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)


class TherapistProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    specialty = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)


# Enter the username as slug field
@receiver(post_save, sender = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def post_save_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    slug = slugify(instance.username)
    User.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).update(slug=slug)
```

En `rbsessions/models.py` tengo una clase llamada Session

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Session(models.Model):

    STATUS_PLANNED = 'PLA'
    STATUS_ARRIVED = 'ARR'
    STATUS_IN_PROGRESS = 'PRO'
    STATUS_ON_LEAVE = 'ONL'
    STATUS_FINISHED = 'FIN'
    STATUS_CANCELLED = 'CAN'

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_PLANNED, u'Planned'),
        (STATUS_ARRIVED, u'Arrived'),
        (STATUS_IN_PROGRESS, u'In progress'),
        (STATUS_FINISHED, u'Finished'),
        (STATUS_CANCELLED, u'Cancelled'),
    )

    description = models.TextField(blank=False)

    date_session = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())

    status = models.CharField(max_length=3,
            choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
            default=STATUS_PLANNED)

    participants = models.TextField(blank=False)

    period = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True)

    game_levels = models.TextField(blank=True)

    iterations = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    # Number of repetitions of each level or game (definir)

    movements = models.TextField(blank=False)

    games = models.TextField(blank=False)

    medical = models.ForeignKey('userprofile.MedicalProfile')

    patient = models.ForeignKey('userprofile.PatientProfile')

    therapist = models.ForeignKey('userprofile.TherapistProfile')
```

Como dice Cesar en la primera respuesta de esta pregunta tengo un import tipo loop o circular pues de cada `models.py` de cada aplicación, estoy importando modelos de la otra. Entonces obtengo este error:

```
(nrb_dev)➜  project-system git:(dev) ✗ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...
System check identified 2 issues (0 silenced).
January 20, 2016 - 14:11:40
Django version 1.9, using settings 'neurorehabilitation.settings.development'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[20/Jan/2016 14:11:42] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6976
[20/Jan/2016 14:13:03] "GET /admin/rbsessions/session/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3715
[20/Jan/2016 14:13:03] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3189
[20/Jan/2016 14:13:07] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6976
[20/Jan/2016 14:13:09] "GET /admin/userprofile/therapistprofile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5368
[20/Jan/2016 14:13:09] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3189
[20/Jan/2016 14:13:11] "GET /admin/userprofile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3734
[20/Jan/2016 14:13:14] "GET /admin/userprofile/patientprofile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7044
[20/Jan/2016 14:13:14] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3189
[20/Jan/2016 14:17:53] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6976
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f3f7a342378>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/bgarcial/workspace/neurorehabilitation-system/rbsessions/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from userprofile.models import MedicalProfile,TherapistProfile, PatientProfile
  File "/home/bgarcial/workspace/neurorehabilitation-system/userprofile/models.py", line 17, in <module>
    from rbsessions.models import Session
ImportError: cannot import name 'Session'
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Las claves foráneas que tengo están es en en la clase Session en donde importo los modelos `MedicalProfile`,`TherapistProfile`, `PatientProfile`.

En la clase `User` yo llamó al modelo `Session` pero no como una llave foránea sino como su clase, para que cuando se cree un usuario con perfil de paciente, se cree también un registro de una sesión de Rehabilitación (Session) para ese paciente. Entonces la estoy llamando de esta forma

```
from rbsessions.models import Session
class User(AbstractUser):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super(User, self).save( *args, **kwargs)
        # Creating and user with patient profile
        if self.is_patient and not PatientProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():
            profile = PatientProfile(user=self)
            profile.save()
            encounter = Session(user=self).save()
```

Y es allí en donde sale mi error de `from rbsessions.models import Session
ImportError: cannot import name 'Session'`

Aunque tengo mis dudas de si puedo decirle a Django que me cree una instancia de una sesión de rehabilitación (dado por la clase Session) de esa forma.

Comment: puedes agregar el fragmento de código donde te arroja la excepción? sospechó que tienes "session" definido en algún otro lado.

Comment: @moscoquera he editado mi pregunta y ya he adicionado la porción de código que tiene que ver con los imports que realizo en el encabezado del archivo. No se si sea necesario adicionar toda la clase o con esto sea suficiente. Muchas gracias

Comment: Me ha funcionado utilizando un import normal del tipo `import rbsessions.models` pero no se porque de la otra manera no funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que tienes problemas por que estás haciendo una importación circular, de `rbsessions/models.py` estas importando modelos de `userprofile/models.py` y viceversa, sería bueno que muestres el código completo de los modelos.

Si lo que estás tratando de hacer es usarlo para `ForeignKey`s, puedes comentar las líneas de las importaciones y usar la notación textual. Por ejemplo:

```
# from rbsessions.models import Session

class MiModelo(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey('rbsessions.Session')
```

### Actualización

No te hagas problemas, lo que yo haría en tu caso es pasar todo a notación textual para los campos que sean llaves foráneas, así te evitas problemas con las importaciones:

```
# rbsessions/models.py

# from userprofile.models import MedicalProfile,TherapistProfile, PatientProfile

class Session(models.Model):
    # ...
    medical = models.ForeignKey('userprofile.MedicalProfile')
    patient = models.ForeignKey('userprofile.PatientProfile')
    therapist = models.ForeignKey('userprofile.TherapistProfile')

# userprofile/models.py

# from rbsessions.models import Session

class MiModelo(models.Model):
    # ...
    session = models.ForeignKey('rbsessions.Session')
```

Con esto, en tus archivos `models.py` ya no deberías tener `from app.models import X` por ningún lado.

Comment: Creo que habia formulado mal mi pregunta antes. Hice una actualización en mi pregunta, en donde es en ese apartado en donde tengo el inconveniente.

Comment: @bgarcial entiendo, recien leo bien la actualización

Comment: @bgarcial en el otro lado ya lo cambiaste a notación textual?

Comment: Si en rbsessions/models.py ya lo tengo en notación textual, y fue mas cosa mia, de la forma en como redacté la pregunta, excúsame.

Comment: @bgarcial puedes actualizar tus `models.py` en la pregunta?

Comment: Los acabo recién de actualizar :)

Comment: @bgarcial en `rbsessions/models.py` sigues usando `from userprofile.models import MedicalProfile,TherapistProfile, PatientProfile`, comentalo o tal vez se te paso en la ultima edición de tu pregunta

Comment: Si, disculpa, creí que los habia comentado. Ya los comenté

Comment: @bgarcial [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34625/discussion-between-cesar-bustios-and-bgarcial).